# weback4 creating vendor file for react component

Tags: webpack

I am using webpack4 for codesplitting in my reactjs application. I am using the following webpack.config.js for reactjs app:

```javascript
 webpack.config.js file:
     const config = {
         entry: {
             client: APP_DIR + '/index.js',
         },
         output: {
             filename: '[name].bundle.dev.js',
             path: BUILD_DIR,
             publicPath : '/js/',
                 chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].js'
             },
             mode : 'development',
             module: {
                 rules: [
                 {
                     test: /\.(jsx|js)?$/,
                     exclude: /(node_modules\/)/,
                     use: {
                         loader: "babel-loader",
                         options: {
                             presets: ['react', 'es2015','stage-2'], // Transpiles JSX and ES6
                         }
                     }
                 },
                 {
                     test: /\.(css)?$/,
                     use: [
                         'css-loader',
                     ],
                 },
             ],
             },
             plugins: [
                 new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                     'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
                 }),
             };
```

routes.js file:

```javascript
import {HomePage,DetailPage} from './reactcomponents';

export default function() {
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route exact={true} path = "/" component={HomePage}/>   
            <Route path = {"/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\ ]*)/abc/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\ ]*)-:listingId"} component={DetailPage}/>
        </Switch>
    )
}
```

after running webpack config, webpack generating 4 files:

- client.bundle.js,
- homepage.bundle.js,
- detailpage.bundle.js
- and vendors~detailpage.bundle.js.

What is the use of "vendors~detailpage.bundle.js" file in webpack4 and
why "vendors~detailpage.bundle.js" file is generating? Is there any webpack config option am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest u read this page [split-chunks-plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/).

As u can see that webpack will automatically split chunks based on these conditions:

1. New chunk can be shared OR modules are from the node_modules folder
2. New chunk would be bigger than 30kb (before min+gz)
3. Maximum number of parallel requests when loading chunks on demand
   would be lower or equal to 5
4. Maximum number of parallel requests at initial page load would be
   lower or equal to 3
5. When trying to fulfill the last two conditions, bigger chunks are
   preferred.

For more info, read the **split chunk plugin** docs